# How do I make the path to a binary file consistent across Python virtual environments?

Tags: python

I'm working on a Python library that requires a certain binary file for some features, which it uses via the subprocess package. I want to have a consistent way to access the path to that binary file, regardless of where a given user has installed the program that contains that binary. Is there a way to include the path to the file in the library for the virtual environment so that the path can be treated as an attribute of some Python package, or is there another solution whereby the path to the binary can be consistently retrieved?

Comment: what does your library structure look like and where is this file in relation to everything in the library

Comment: @DerekEden, the binary could be in any location on the end user's computer.

Comment: Is this binary you're looking for an executable that might be located in a directory pointed at by the _PATH_ environment variable already? Probably not. 1. Your code could look for the file 2. Your code could ask the user interactively on the console prompt or with a GUI dialog box. 3. You could let the user write the path to the binary in a configuration file that your code would read at run time.

Answer (score 0):

if the file can be anywhere you could search for it, though this could potentially take a while...

```
def find(name, path):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        if name in files:
            return os.path.join(root, name)
```

you'd have to set path as something like the root folder on linux for it to look everywhere